# In Robot Framework - Can you run a test from the 'fail' point

Tags: selenium, robotframework

In Robot Framework, could you initiate session from the point of where a 'fail' occurred. Example, I want to open google > find 'Images' > click 'Images' and let's assume it did not find 'Images' (maybe my OS is in JP and 'Images' is actually '画像' etc.) is there a command or a keyword that would let me run the test again, in the same session, and continue from the 'fail' point and onward?

I hope that made sense.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can**. But you need to use the python debugger pdb.
I recommend you to read the doc, that explains clearly how to setup. Is clearly explained and, as I'm not a python/robot developer, I can make some mistake trying to write an example.

> See section 3.2.2 - Continue on failure:
>   http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-the-python-debugger-pdb

Anyway **it is not a good practice**. Tests should test and if they encounter some error, they shoud fail. Otherwise it is not a test, only a bunch of code! I only recomend to use this way to help you write a test case of something broken and to be repaired, but not to test your platform.